# Where is the syntax error located in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have a syntax problem somewhere but can't spot it as I am not a javascript developer. Can someone with a better eye point out the problem?

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: / + 'modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-ajax-back.php',
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
        data: (all ? '' : $('input[name="categoryBox[]"]').serialize()+'&')+(id_layered_filter ? 'id_layered_filter='+parseInt(id_layered_filter)+'' : ''),
        success: function(result) {
```

Comment: Start by formatting your code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is on this line...

```
url: / +     'modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-ajax-back.php',
```

The `/` is misplaced, and should be...

```
url: '/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-ajax-back.php',
```

Comment: Thanks - I discovered that the typo is generated in my PrestaShop backoffice because my url contains an extra directory that should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `url:` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: / +     'modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-ajax-back.php',
      // ^^ here
    data: (all ? '' :     $('input[name="categoryBox[]"]').serialize()+'&')+(id_layered_filter ?    'id_layered_filter='+parseInt(id_layered_filter)+'' : ''),
    success: function(result) {
```

The correct code should be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-ajax-back.php',
    data: (all ? '' :     $('input[name="categoryBox[]"]').serialize()+'&')+(id_layered_filter ?    'id_layered_filter='+parseInt(id_layered_filter)+'' : ''),
    success: function(result) {
```